# cython structure, string from python to cython

Tags: python, c, cython

i would like to convert a python object to cython structure by doing as i did bellow, but it doesn't assigns the values of simres[1] to the resulta[x].cpt1

```
cdef struct resultaStructure:
    double score
    char **cpt1

simRes = [1.0,
['http://bioontology.org/projects/ontologies/fma/fmaOwlDlComponent_2_0#Abdomen', 
'Abdomen']]
cdef x = 0 
cdef resultaStructure *resulta = <resultaStructure *> malloc(sizeof(resultaStructure)*labelsSourceTaille)

resulta[x].score = simRes[0]
print("score : ",resulta[0].score)

resulta[x].cpt1 = <char**> malloc (sizeof (char**)*2)
print('2')
resulta[x].cpt1[0] = <char*> malloc (sizeof (char)*simRes[1][0].__len__()+1)
print('3')
resulta[x].cpt1[1] = <char*> malloc (sizeof (char)*simRes[1][1].__len__()+1)
print('4')
resulta[x].cpt1[0] = <char*> simRes[1][0]
print('5')
resulta[x].cpt1[1] = <char*>  simRes[1][1]
print('6')

print("cpt1 0 : ",resulta[0].cpt1[0])
print("cpt1 1 : ",resulta[0].cpt1[1])
```

here is the result

> ('score :', 1.0)
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question and in OP's answer has serious issues which will likely cause the program to crash in the long term.

### 1)

```
resulta[x].cpt1 = <char**> malloc (sizeof (char**)*2)
```

`cpt1` is a pointer to (an array of) char pointers. Thus it should be assigned as

```
resulta[x].cpt1 = <char*> malloc (sizeof (char*)*2)
```

(Better yet, if the length is always `2` then assign `char *cpt1[2]` in the struct definition and you don't need to `malloc` it.)

This is unlikely to cause a real problem since all pointers are the same size but it's still wrong.

### 2) (The real problem part a)

```
resulta[x].cpt1[0] = <char*> malloc (sizeof (char)*simRes[1][0].__len__()+1)
# ...
resulta[x].cpt1[0] = <char*>some_python_string
```

Here you allocate some memory, the promptly forget about the memory you've allocated if favour of making the pointer point at a different area of memory owned by the Python string. What you *don't* do is copy data from the Python string into your allocated memory.

### 3) (The real problem part b)

```
str1 = simRes[1][0].encode('UTF-8')
resulta[x].cpt1[0] = <char*> str1
```

The memory that `cpt1[0]` points to is owned by `str1`. If `str1` gets freed before you've finished using your structure then the structure points to invalid memory and your program will crash, or read some random data that's allocated later, or some other bad thing.

If you can guarantee that `str1` will outlive your structure (for example, your structure is used as an argument for one C function call) then this is OK, but in the general case it probably isn't.

The solution is to copy the contents or `str1` into your newly allocated memory:

```
resulta[x].cpt1[0] = <char*> malloc (sizeof (char)*len(simRes[1][0])+1)
strcpy(resulta[x].cpt1[0],str1)
```

---

(Also, You are remembering to `free` all the memory you've `malloc`ed, right?)

Comment: thank you , you made it very clear to me. It was a problem that took me some time to resolve, but as you said, it may crash because of the issues you mentioned. For the second point is it ok to point to python memory, to use for no gil process ?, because my purpose is to use cython parallel with no gil.

Comment: It's fine to point to Python memory without the GIL. Make sure your thread hold a reference to the memory before releasing the GIL. You want to be careful to ensure that your other threads aren't changing the exact same memory while you're looking at it otherwise you may get confusing results. (It's OK and common to have multiple threads changing different elements of the same array though). Strings are supposed to be immutable so they shouldn't get changed and this should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is by encoding the python string before assignment as follow ,

```
str1 = simRes[1][0].encode('UTF-8')
resulta[x].cpt1[0] = <char*> str1
print('5')
str2 = simRes[1][1].encode('UTF-8')
resulta[x].cpt1[1] = <char*> str2
```